# Two exponential random variables

Tags: probability

> Batteries A and B have lifetimes that are independent and
>   exponentially distributed with a common mean of m years. The
>   probability that battery B outlasts battery A by more than one year is
>   0.33. Calculate m.

I am pretty lost. I know that A, B must be ~ exp($\lambda = 1/m$). Are we calculating P(B > A+1)?

(Finan exam p 39.29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we need $\Bbb P(B>A+1)$, and since we know the densities of the two independent variables, using $k=1/m$, it is simpler to type than $\lambda$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\rho_A(x)\; dx &= ke^{-kx}\; dx\ ,\\
\rho_B(y)\; dy &= ke^{-ky}\; dy\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
we have to compute
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Bbb P(B>A+1)
&=
\iint_{y>x+1}
\rho_A(x)\; dx\; 
\rho_B(y)\; dy
\\
&=
\iint_{y>x+1}
ke^{-kx}\; dx\; 
ke^{-ky}\; dy
\\
&=
\int_{x=0}^\infty
ke^{-kx}\; dx\; 
\int_{y=x+1}^{\infty}
ke^{-ky}\; dy
\\
&=
\int_{x=0}^\infty
ke^{-kx}\; dx\; 
\int_{y=x+1}^{\infty}
-(e^{-ky})'\; dy
\\
&=
\int_{x=0}^\infty
ke^{-kx}\; dx\; 
e^{-k(x+1)}
\\
&=
e^{-k}
\int_{x=0}^\infty
ke^{-2kx}\; dx
\\
&=
\frac 12
e^{-k}
\int_{x=0}^\infty
-(e^{-2kx})'\; dx
\\
&=
\frac 12
e^{-k}
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This leads to value of $k$, and then of $m$...

```
sage: -log(2*0.33) 
0.415515443961666
sage: 1/_          
2.40664941467797
```

Answer (score 2):

Mean $m$ years implies that $m = 1/\lambda \implies \lambda = 1/m$. This is because you need an actual distribution parameter $\lambda$ rather than given mean for calculations below (although your exam might have meant $m$ is a parameter, in which case calculations below still apply, but the final step will be different).

You have to do some re-writing. First, $$\mathbb{P}[B > A + 1] = \mathbb{P}[\cup_{x}(B > x + 1) \cap (A = x)] = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{x+1}^{\infty}\lambda*e^{-\lambda x}\lambda*e^{-\lambda y}dy dx = \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{2}$$

Now, since you know the probability, you can write $$\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{2} = 0.33 \implies e^{-\lambda} = 0.66 \implies -\lambda = \ln0.66 \implies \lambda = -\ln0.66$$
If you original task meant $\lambda = 1/m$, then just express $m$ through $\lambda$, if it meant $\lambda = m$, you have the answer.